# Embedded Ignite instance with persistence enabled is restarting very slow

Tags: java, caching, ignite

I have java application with embedded ignite instance. Ignite is running with persistence enabled.

Since ignite storage became large (about 5 GB) java application I faced the problem with too slow restart. When application is starting ignite starts about 5-8 minutes.

Here are configs :

```
final DataStorageConfiguration dataConf = new DataStorageConfiguration();
dataConf.setMetricsEnabled(true);
final DataRegionConfiguration dataRegionConf = new DataRegionConfiguration();
dataRegionConf.setName(regionName);
dataRegionConf.setMetricsEnabled(true);
dataRegionConf.setInitialSize(100 * 1024 * 1024);
dataRegionConf.setMaxSize(10000 * 1024 * 1024);
dataRegionConf.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
dataConf.setDataRegionConfigurations(dataRegionConf);
```

Is it possible to speed up ignite start somehow?

Comment: What do you see in logs? You can take a thread dump with a `jstack` utility and see, what the node is doing.

Comment: Please provide more details. How do you stop the nodes before restart? Do you deactivate before stopping? How many caches are there, what are the configurations? What is the storage type (HDD, SSD, etc)?